# Which company name should appear on my resume?

Tags: resume

I have worked for the same company for 13 years.  The first 3 years, my employment was through our parent company.  The last 10 years, I've worked for the subsidiary company but the subsidiary actually does not have any employees.  We all share the same office space.

To make this even more complicated, we use an HR company and so my W-2 comes from the HR company.  I'm not sure how to list this on my resume.  Currently I have all 13 years listed as employed by my original employer (parent company).  Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

> 2007-2020 Yoyodyne (a subsidiary of ACME Global)

Mention first, *by its most recent name*, the place you're bragging about (yeah, with 13 years you should brag. shamelessly. it's a big deal.)  Then, just to clarify, mention the corporate overlord. People in your line of work will recognize the former, and executives will recognize the latter (or pretend to :-).

Remember, the purpose of a resume is to get the interview. It's a resume, not a company legal document. Nobody is going to investigate whether you got the corporate history right. (If they do, great. It's a topic of conversation in the interview.)

You definitely don't have to mention the HR company in your resume. Your hiring manager doesn't care one bit.  The HR people who do background checks know what all that HR company stuff means.